# Can't publish 2010 list workflows into SP365 (using SPDesigner 2013.1)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, workflow

For **2013** workflows, it works fine. No issues.

However, when I publish a **2010** list workflow, I can only see it in the workflows list of SPD. (I can't see it either SP365 or list view in SPD). 
The workflow seems to be saved in SPD, but it is not associated to any list and it can't see it anywhere in SP365.
Any ideas what it might be wrong here? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In workflow click on "Check Error" button before publishing workflow. Might be some error is coming at the time of publishing. If on click of "Check Error" it gives no error message then publish it again and check.

Comment: already tried that 100 times. didn't work.

Comment: Try with adding single action and check. I have created many workflow of 2010 for SharePoint 2013 environment.

Comment: are you using which machine? windows 7 or windows 8?

Comment: I am trying with single actions. No success. I also did many 2010 workflows in 13 environment with success in the past. But recently stoped working.  windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in previous version of SharePoint Designer there is bug. Try to install newer version.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039732
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2817441

Comment: Thanks. I am already running with SPD SP1 but it won't work. The problem is probably something else